# Question about nGon

Tags: vertices

Ive just retopologized this sculpt, but theres a few faces i can't connect without causing distortion as there are 5 sides and when you look from the side view the vertices all run in a column but don't have anywhere to join (pic 2).

Ive tried just joining the faces together and then seeing if the knife tool but it causes the same thing to happen on the face next to it.

Any help?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: De select everything (Pressing "A" once or twice) then select the edge loop you are pointing to with your red arrow and then delete it. Press "X" > Delete Edge Loop. Repeat for the other one. Then if you like you can add complete edge loops back.

Comment: you can create a loop on the remaining faces with Ctrl+R, this will give you a missing loop because of the ngon
then select the last 2 verticies on the sides and hit j to join them